# C++ variant containing a map of itself

Tags: c++, c++17, self-reference, std-variant

I would like to be able to create a variant that contains a `std::map<std::string, MyVariant>` as one of its cases. The ideal would be able to write something like

```cpp
using MyVariant = std::variant<int, std::string, std::map<std::string, MyVariant>>;
```

but this requires forward declaration.

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked previously, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67865145/17789309) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53502760/17789309), but these have mainly been focused on the case of `std::vector`, and since C++17 `std::vector` is allowed to use incomplete types, while `std::map` does not.

In particular, I'm wondering if the fixed-point combinator solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504373/17789309) would work in this case? Adapting the code from that answer:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

// non-recursive definition
template<typename T>
using VariantImpl = std::variant<int, std::string, std::map<std::string, T>>;

// fixed-point combinator
template<template<typename> typename K>
struct FixCombinator : K<FixCombinator<K>>
{
    using K<FixCombinator>::K;
};

using MyVariant = FixCombinator<VariantImpl>;
```

However if there's another way to do it, I would be interested with that also.

Comment: What compiler are you using? [this compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/h3bnG965c)

Comment: @KamilCuk - I want to avoid undefined behavior. Unfortunately successful compilation on some compiler is no guarantee of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible (at least by standard guarantees), since `std::variant` requires the used types to be complete and `std::map` requires key and value type to be complete types at the point of instantiation. But your construction will be complete only after it's instantiation.

The only standard containers allowing such a recursive construction (at least to some degree) are `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::forward_list`.

If you want to use `std::map` and have standard guarantees for it, you need to add one level of indirection at some point.

Comment: Would `std::map<std::string, std::any>` be a suitable extra level of indirection?

Comment: @Eljay Sure, but you don't need to make it that complicated. `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<T>>` in OP's example would be enough. `std::unique_ptr` does not require it's type to be complete.